# Dynamic meta data for each page with same header

Tags: php, dynamic, header, web

I would like to add different title and description for each pages with the same header

I've the following code but this doesn't seems to work

```
<?php 
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; switch 
($page)
{ 

case 'index.php':
$title= 'uHost | Unlimited Free Hosting' ; 
$description = 'Free Web Hosting with Unlimited Disk Space, Unlimited Bandwidth, Unlimitted Database and Unlimited Websites from uHost. With PHP and MySQL and no forced ads on your site.'; 
$keywords = 'uhost,uHost,home,unlimitted free hosting,unlimitted disk space,unlimitted websites hosting,free cpanel hosting,hosting free,free hosting sites,domain,free domain';
break;

case 'login.php': 
$title= 'Login | uHost'; 
$description = 'Login to your uHost control panel in order to change the settings of your website.'; 
$keywords = 'uhost,uHost,login,unlimitted free hosting,unlimitted disk space,unlimitted websites hosting,free cpanel hosting,hosting free,free hosting sites,domain,free domain';
break; 
}
?>
```

I've saved this as a php file and included it in my header, and echo ed each variables.

But this doesn't seems to work

And if i set a default case every page seems to have same title, description etc

How to fix this?

Comment: Please paste what you are getting in $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Comment: Make sure that you are getting the value you want in switch case. For example `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for http://example.com/foo/bar.php returns `/foo/bar.php`.

Comment: Thanks guys. $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] was getting '/index.php' . I missed the slash